# Passing $_SESSION variable between pages

Tags: php, session-variables

Edit: the session_start() was in the "entire code of initial page," but wasn't showing.  I needed another newline.

Edit 2: Showing the output of the raw HTML rather than the displayed page.

I am working on a document conversion site.  It takes a one or two page .docx file and converts it to simple html.  (Basically replacing newlines with p tags, no html or head tags as it will be displayed in an existing page).  For test purposes I'm converting a .docx file with a single word - "one" - in it.

I am storing the converted data as a string in the variable $_SESSSION['doc'].  Because of the issues I've been having, I'm also storing a $_SESSION['test'] string.

I do a var_dump($_SESSION) on the initial page and I can see both variables with populated strings.

I do a var_dump($_SESSION) on the following screen, and the $_SESSION['test'] string comes through okay, but the $_SESSION['doc'] is now a 0 length string.  I'm not certain what's truncating my 'doc' string.

The relevant variables are $_SESSION['doc'], $_SESSION['test'], and $outputData.  I included the entire first page at the end of this post since I suspect $outputData is getting overwritten.

I believe this is the relevant code snippet for the initial page:

```
<?php $outputData = preg_replace("/.+/", "<p class='converted'>$0</p>", $outputData);
                              $outputData = preg_replace("/<\/p>\n\n/", "<br /><br /></p>", $outputData); ?>
                <?php if(isset($outputData)){$_SESSION['doc'] = $outputData;}else{$_SESSION['doc']="JustATest";} $_SESSION['test'] = "<>()!';!SDFSDFG^%$"; echo "\n<div><br /><br />var_dump: " . var_dump($_SESSION) . "</div>"; ?>
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
["doc"]=>
string(32) "<p class='converted'>one</p>
"
["test"]=>
string(18) "<>()!';!SDFSDFG^%$"
```

Relevant code on the follow up page:

```
<?php if(session_id() == ''){session_start();}

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce;

$woocommerce->show_messages();
?>

<div>session_id: <?php echo session_id(); ?><br />OUTPUT: <?php echo var_dump($_SESSION); ?></div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
```

Output of follow up page:

```
session_id: jl40cdmbdpd3h40qg3ogmghkp0
OUTPUT: array(2) { ["doc"]=> string(0) "" ["test"]=> string(18) "<>()!';!SDFSDFG^%$" }
```

EDIT: I wasn't viewing the raw HTML.  /me shakes head.

```
IGNORE: One thing I found strange on the initial page is the single word "one" is showing up as a 32 char string. . . so there seems to be some extraneous white space after the document conversion. . . but it still outputs from the $_SESSION['doc'] variable on the initial screen.
```

Entire code for the initial page:

```
<?php if(session_id() == '' ){session_start();}

if(isset($_POST['added']))
{
add_basic_edit( $_POST['id'], $_POST['wc'] );
unset($_POST['added']);
header('Location: http://localhost/cart/');
exit;
}
/* Template Name: Upload Page */ get_header();

/**
 * Test code to programmatically add a pricing calculator product to the cart, on
 * every page load
 */
function add_basic_edit( $product_id, $num_words ) {

global $wc_measurement_price_calculator;

$product = get_product( $product_id );  // id of my 'word' product

$measurements = $wc_measurement_price_calculator->get_product_measurements( $product );

// get the one measurement
foreach ( $measurements as $measurement ) ;

$measurement->set_value( $num_words );  // the number of words

// add to cart
$wc_measurement_price_calculator->add_to_cart( $product->id, $measurement );
/var/www/html/websites/localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Avada/upload.php}

if(isset($_POST['posted']))
{
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

class DocumentConverterClient {
    var $url = '';

    function convert($inputFile, $outputType) {
        $this->url="http://localhost:8080/jodconverter-sample-webapp-3.0-SNAPSHOT/converted/$inputFile.$outputType";
        $request = new HTTP_Request2($this->url);
        $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST)
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
            ->addPostParameter('outputFormat', $outputType)
            ->setBody($inputData);
        $request->addUpload('inputDocument', $inputFile);

        return $request->send()->getBody();
    }
}

$documentConverter = new DocumentConverterClient();

$inputFile = $_FILES['inputDocument']['tmp_name'];
$outputType='txt';
$noext=current(explode(".", $_FILES["inputDocument"]["name"]));
$inputType=end(explode(".", $_FILES["inputDocument"]["name"]));
$outputFile = "data/$noext.$outputType";

$outputData = $documentConverter->convert($inputFile, $outputType);
//file_put_contents($outputFile, $outputData);
} ?>

<div class="column_group"><br /><br />
    <div style="float:left;width:30%;" class="left_clumn">
        <div style="float:left;width:35%">Wordcount:</div><div><?php $wc = str_word_count($outputData); echo $wc;?>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:35%">Price Per Word:</div><div>$<?php $product_id=get_page_by_title('Basic Editing', 'OBJECT', 'Product' ); $product = get_product( $product_id->ID ); $ppw = $product->get_price(); echo $ppw;?>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:35%">Total Price:</div><div>$<?php echo number_format(($wc * $ppw),2);?>
        </div>
        <div><br /><br />
            <form name="add_to_cart" id="add_to_cart" action="../upload-page/" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="added" value="added" />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $product_id->ID; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="wc" value="<?php echo $wc; ?>" />
                <?php $outputData = preg_replace("/.+/", "<p class='converted'>$0</p>", $outputData);
                              $outputData = preg_replace("/<\/p>\n\n/", "<br /><br /></p>", $outputData); ?>
                <?php if(isset($outputData)){$_SESSION['doc'] = $outputData;}else{$_SESSION['doc']="JustATest";} $_SESSION['test'] = "<>()!';!SDFSDFG^%$"; echo "\n<div><br /><br />var_dump: " . var_dump($_SESSION) . "</div>"; ?>
                <span class="BlueButton" onclick="document.getElementById('add_to_cart').submit()">Add to Cart</span>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width:70%;" class="right_column">
        <div><?php echo $outputData; ?></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content" style="<?php echo $content_css; ?>">
</div>
<div id="sidebar" style="<?php echo $sidebar_css; ?>"><?php generated_dynamic_sidebar(); ?></div>
<?php get_footer(); unset($_POST['posted']); ?>
```

Comment: have you done `session_start()` check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: also, the session_start() has to be on every page

Comment: Judging by your `$outputData` not having any markup after processing and being 32 (mostly non-printing) characters long, I'd look to your original source string and the regular expressions. I did a very brief check to see if I could find anything about illegal characters in session data and didn't find anything, but it's an issue you will have to address eventually anyway.

Comment: Thank you both.  session_start() was there, I just messed the formatting of it up in my post.

Comment: Jerry, longer docs *do* get markup.  Good catch on the short one not getting any. . . and, yeah, I'll need to make a white list of valid chars and dump the rest.

Comment: Jerry, I feel silly.  Here's the output of the raw HTML. . . which accounts for most the extra chars:

    array(2) {
    ["doc"]=>
    string(32) "<p class='converted'>one</p>
    "
    ["test"]=>
    string(18) "<>()!';!SDFSDFG^%$"

Answer (score 1):

You must add `session_start()` to the top of all pages before **anything** is rendered as output to the page.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: The line <?php if(session_id() == ''){session_start();}

is the first thing in both pages.

Comment: `session_start()` needs to come even before the `if` statement.

Comment: I made session_start() with no if statement the first thing, and I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor answer as I still don't know why $_SESSION['doc'] was getting overwritten, particularly since $_SESSION['test'] was retained.  I think it has to do with my various if(isset()) statements for processing form data.  I believe one of them was at some point overwritting $outputData. . . but I'm not certain where.

I changed the first such statement to grab outputData from the _POST variable:

```
if(isset($_POST['added']))
{
    add_basic_edit( $_POST['id'], $_POST['wc'] );
    unset($_POST['added']);
    $_SESSION['doc'] = $_POST['outputData'];
    header('Location: http://techleadnet.com/cart/');
    exit;
}
```

I added a hidden input to the form, and a couple more regexes to get rid of single and double quotes:

```
$outputData = preg_replace("/\"/", "&quot;", $outputData);
$outputData = preg_replace("/\'/","&rsquo;", $outputData);

<input type="hidden" name="outputData" value="<?php echo $outputData; ?>" />
```

If anybody can point out where I'm messing up either the $_SESSION['doc'] variable, or where $outputData is getting overwritten this would be a better answer.

I *did* try making session_start(), without an if statement, the first thing in both of these pages, but it didn't make a difference.